# SED change text between matches without affecting the matches

Tags: bash, sed

I have some text

```
#MATCH1
command 1
command 2
command 3
#MATCH2

sed -i '/MATCH1/,/MATCH2/' s/^/#/' <filename>
```

Does

```
##MATCH1
#command 1
#command 2
#command 3
##MATCH2
```

And what i want is

```
#MATCH1
#command 1
#command 2
#command 3
#MATCH2
```

Anyone has any idea how to do this? Without post processing the output

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` that make sure we don't have `#` at line start:

```
sed '/MATCH1/,/MATCH2/ s/^[^#]/#&/' file
```

```
#MATCH1
#command 1
#command 2
#command 3
#MATCH2
```

Note that this only matches non-empty lines between given keywords. Alternatively you may use this `sed`:

```
sed '/MATCH1/,/MATCH2/ { /^#/! s/^/#/; }' file
```

Comment: What does the "&" stand for?

Comment: `&` is back-reference of the complete match by regex.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for doing s/old/new, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '/MATCH2/{f=0} f{$0="#" $0} /MATCH1/{f=1} 1' file
#MATCH1
#command 1
#command 2
#command 3
#MATCH2
```

That will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box and is utterly trivial to modify if/when you want to do anything else.